# R: Assign corresponding ID's polygon to points in shapefile according to coordinates

Tags: r, gis, shapefile

I have two shapefiles. The first is a polygon shapefile of regions, each of them has an unique ID. The second one is a point shapefile with event occured in the regions of shapefile1.

I would like to assign to  each event (row) of the point shapefile the corresponding region ID of the polygon shapefile.

Any ideas on how to do this with R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the two spacial files have the same ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should be able to use `over()`.

```
Points_w_Region <- over(points,regions) ## Get the information
Points$regions <- Points_w_Region ## Assign the information to the data
```

This will assign the regions obtained through over to each of the points.
`over()` is a part of the sp package and I am making the assumption that your data is within the sp structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion was exactly what I needed.